# Borderless windows but keep title bar

Tags: themes, window-decoration

I don't really like the look of the borders on the windows of applications I'm running. I've tried disabling window decorator, but that takes away the title bar and shadow as well. Ideally, I would like to see it as described in [this article](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/ubuntu-ambiance-radiance-themes-are-now.html), where they include the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by editing the metacity file of the theme you're using. Open up terminal and type

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml
```

Where `gedit` is your favorite text editor and `Ambiance` is your theme.

Near the top of the file, under **general window layout**, you'll see something like this:

```
  <distance name="left_width" value="1"/>
  <distance name="right_width" value="1"/>
  <distance name="bottom_height" value="1"/>
```

Those numbers indicate the thickness of the borders around windows. In order to get rid of the borders, change the three numbers to 0.